# Getting leftmost or rightmost valid characters using regex

Tags: .net, regex

I am looking for regular expressions compatible with Regex.Replace in .NET to filter down user input to the leftmost or rightmost valid characters.  For instance if i need to get only uppercase characters I can do:

```
var userText = "Ukeaf-4DeT";
var userPattern = @"[^A-Z]";
var validText = Regex.Replace(userText, userPattern, string.Empty)
```

will return UDT but I need the userPattern to specify leftmost 2 valid characters so UD in this case.  Likewise, I need a separate userPattern that would do the rightmost 2 valid characters (DT in this example).

Is this possible to do with a single Regex pattern and how?

Comment: Regular expressions are sentences describing patterns. If you can explain the pattern easily in one expression, use one. If it's easier to explain in two expressions, use two. There's no reason to write a run-on.

Comment: In your example, should `t` be `T` ?

Comment: zzzzBov, the user will only be able to input one pattern so it will be necessary to do what I am trying to do within one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but ugly. As zzzzBov noted there usually is no reason why to fit everything in one regular expression. But as many things, it is possible to do.

```
string twoFirst = "[^A-Z]|(?<=([A-Z].*){2})[A-Z]";
string twoLast = "[^A-Z]|[A-Z](?=(.*[A-Z]){2})";
string userText = "Ukeaf-4DeT";
string validText = Regex.Replace(userText, twoFirst, string.Empty);
```

Using the `twoFirst` expression it will remove all but the two first occurrences of capital letters. Whats special about the two first capital letters is that they do not have 2 or more capital letters before them. This is what this expression checks for. Any character which isn't a capital letter, or if it have at least two capital letters before it, will be removed.

This can be generalized to something that generates the patterns needed:

```
string userText = "Ukeaf-4DeT";
int numOccurrences = 2;
string positivePattern = "[A-Z]";
string negativePattern = "[^A-Z]";

string first = negativePattern + "|(?<=(" + positivePattern + ".*){" + numOccurrences + "})" + positivePattern;
string last = negativePattern + "|" + positivePattern + "(?=(.*" + positivePattern + "){" + numOccurrences + "})";
string validText = Regex.Replace(userText, first, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Amazing, very well thought out answer, and complete.